# Blazor - How to call a function with paramenter from SfGrid and GridColumn

Tags: c#, blazor

I am starting to learn Blazor (on my own so I acept any good tips and tutorials).
Now, I have a DB with 2 tables - Equipaments and Interventions.
1 equipament can have many interventions but 1 intervention has only 1 equipament.
So, I was using a html table and I did this:

```
<table class="tableEquipamentos">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="15%">Nome</th>
                            <th width="15%">Marca</th>
                            <th width="15%">Modelo</th>
                            <th width="15%">Utilizador</th>
                            <th width="30%">Observações</th>
                            <th width="10%">Nº Int</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var equipamento in equipamentos.OrderByDescending(e => e.Nome))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold;" @onclick="() => MostrarInfoEquipamento(equipamento.IdEquipamento)">@equipamento.Nome</td>
                                <td>@equipamento.Marca</td>
                                <td>@equipamento.Modelo</td>
                                <td>@equipamento.Utilizador</td>
                                <td>@equipamento.Observacoes</td>
                                <td>@NumeroIntervencoesCount(equipamento.IdMigracao)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

```
public String NumeroIntervencoesCount(int equipamentoAtual)
    {
        int numeroCount = 0;

        foreach(var _intervencoes in intervencoes)
        {
            if(_intervencoes.IdEquipamento.ToString() == equipamentoAtual.ToString())
            {
                numeroCount += 1;
            }

        }

        return numeroCount.ToString();
    }
```

Now, I found out about SfGrid and SyncFusion stuff.

What I was trying to do was the same thing but I do not know how to insert the parameter.
Any help?

```
<SfGrid DataSource="@equipamentos" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true">
                    <GridPageSettings PageSize="20"></GridPageSettings>
                        <GridColumns>
                            <GridColumn 
                                Field=@nameof(Equipamento.Nome) 
                                HeaderText="Nome Equipamento" 
                                TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" 
                                Width="200">
                            </GridColumn>
                            <GridColumn 
                                Field=@nameof(Equipamento.Marca) 
                                HeaderText="Marca" 
                                TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" 
                                Width="200">
                            </GridColumn>
                            <GridColumn 
                                Field=@nameof(Equipamento.Modelo) 
                                HeaderText="Modelo" 
                                TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" 
                                Width="200">
                            </GridColumn>
                            <GridColumn 
                                Field=@nameof(Equipamento.Utilizador)
                                HeaderText="Utilizador" 
                                TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" 
                                Width="200">
                            </GridColumn>
                            <GridColumn
                                HeaderText="Nº Intervenções">
                                @NumeroIntervencoesCount(this.equipamentos.First().IdEquipamento)
                            </GridColumn>
                        </GridColumns>
                </SfGrid>
```

Comment: It seams you do it correct by use `Field=@nameof(Equipamento.Utilizador)` can you explain what is not working when using your sample?

Comment: @DanielW. the error is where:
<GridColumn
HeaderText="Nº Intervenções">
@NumeroIntervencoesCount(this.equipamentos.First().IdEquipamento)
</GridColumn>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Calculate Column Value Based on Other Columns in Blazor DataGrid](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/how-to/calculate-column-value-based-on-other-columns)

You can do this like

```
<GridColumn
   Field=@nameof(Equipamento.IdEquipamento)
   HeaderText="Nº Intervenções">
      <Template>
      @{                    
         <div> 
         $@NumeroIntervencoesCount(value)
         </div>
        }
    </Template>
</GridColumn>
```